# Share a single calendar with iCloud

Tags: icloud, calendar, sharing

I would like to share one of my calendars with a friend, without uploading my other calendars, and without making this shared calendar public. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

If on mac:

- Open up calendar app.
- Right click on the specific calendar you want to share with someone.
- Click on "Share Calendar..."
- Write the name of iCloud user you want to share that calendar with.

If on ios:

- Open up calendar app.
- Find the calendar you want to share.
- Press the "i" icon aligned at the right of each calendar.
- Click "Add Person" and write your friends iCloud adress, name, whatever..

I gotta mention it mainly works on iCloud calendars, not for lets say "Google" account's calendar.

I hope it helps, feel free to comment here if you got any more question.

Comment: I am signed out of iCloud and don't see the option after the right-click. It seems to require being signed it to iCloud, which requires uploading **all** calendars before sharing only one, is that right?

Comment: If you are signed in, you can list all the calendars assigned to accounts, which is iCloud in this case. You can view all of the calendars but only what you share will be shared. Go online with your iCloud on your Mac and try the steps I mentioned above.

Comment: Right. What I would like, and mentioned in the question, is uploading and sharing one calendar, without uploading any of my other calendars.

Answer (score 0):

I post my solution in case it helps someone. I considered and gave up on three providers:

- Google Calendar, because the calendar would either be public on the internet or the other person would need to set up a Google Account and link it to their device (which they are too busy to do);
- Amazon Workmail, because the person would either need to check the calendar on the web, or link their device (again, they are too busy to do);
- iCloud, because I would need to upload **all** my local calendars, which for privacy I did not want to do.

My solution was to export the local Calendar to an `.ics` file, and code a function on my NodeJS server that served that file under three conditions:

- the URL contains a secret key
- the URL contains a GET parameter with a secret key
- the request comes from a pre-approved IP address.

And it works well. Here is the NodeJS code:

```js
/**
 *
 * GET /calendar
 *
 * URL: http://domain.com/secret1?secret2=secret2
 *
 **/
router.get('/secret1', async (req, res) => {

  // Access control
  let ips = ["", ":::fff:127.0.0.1"];
  if (!(ips.includes(req.ip))) {
    return res.redirect("/404");
  }
  if ("secret2" != req.query.secret2) {
    return res.redirect("/404");
  }
  let filepath = path.join(__dirname, "cal.ics");
  if (!fs.existsSync(filepath)) {
    console.error("*** Error in serving calendar file");
    return res.redirect("/404");
  }

  res.sendFile(filepath);
});
```